# To apply a function through a mask on an image

Tags: matlab, masking, impoly

I create a closed region on a picture by `impoly('Closed', true)` and lastly after marking the area for the mask `BW = createMask(h)` in Matlab commandline.
Initial commands before marking points for the mask in the figure

```
imshow('contour.png');
h = impoly('Closed',true);
```

Here, I used **nkjt's** answer below.
The picture to be filtered by the function **conditionalRemoval(image, area)**

[image]

Then, I run

```
image = imread('contour.png');
areaLazyRemoval = BW; 
image = conditional_removal(image, areaLazyRemoval);
```

I now have the [mask](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/mask_1.mat) and the picture.
I should apply the function **conditional_removal** to them.

**How can you use this mask now and apply the function to it in the its marked region?**

My function **conditional_removal**'s pseudocode is

```
function [ image ] = conditional_removal( image, areaLazyRemoval )
   % dim image 794 x 1001 x 3 uint
   % dim areaLazyRemoval 794 x 1001 logical
   image(:,:,1) .* areaLazyRemoval;    % TODO wrong operator here!
   % all pixels marked by logical ones in areaLazyRemoval should get lazyRemoval applied
   % else greedyRemoval so zero
   %
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% lazy removal function
% so remove by 50% chance the thing
function pixel = lazyRemoval(pixel)
if randn > 0
    pixel = 0;
end 
% TODO how to apply pixel-wise removal to the logical matrix and image?
```

**How can you apply the pixel-wise removal to the image by the logical matrix, mask?**

Comment: You have to pass you data to `createfigure` to plot it. What is the code for `createfigure`?

Comment: @DanielR It is this one: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/createfigure.m

Comment: I provided a SSCCE example of the problem such that you can reproduce the problem. There is now a minimal picture of the problem, code how it is created, code how it is used and the Error.

Comment: I updated the body according to nkjt's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this:

> impoly > Generate Data > function createfigure1

Do you mean after calling impoly, you go into the figure window and select "Generate Code"? Which will create a function `createfigure` - but this has nothing to do with `impoly`.

There are a couple of ways you can extract the ROI.
After choosing the area with `impoly`, before closing the figure:

`BW = createMask(h);`

Or you can extract the position with `getPosition` and then use `roipoly`.

Comment: The problem is that if I try to use **BW = createMask(h)**, I cannot type anything when the figure is active: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202013-11-25%20at%2014.25.30.png Can you give an example how you can use **getPostion** and **roipoly** now, please.

Comment: That's because you're calling `position = wait(h);` Do you need to?

Comment: I do not need the command. It was a mistake and I did not notice it. Thank you very much for your answer! I updated the body to consider now the main problem, how to apply a function through a mask on an image.

Answer (score 0):

The last problems were in the function **conditional_removal** and in creating the **randn_logical_matrix**.

Matlab docs of **randn** says

> RN = distributed.randn(..., classname) specifies the class of the
>   distributed array D. Valid choices are the same as for the regular
>   randn function: 'double' (the default), 'single', 'int8', 'uint8',
>   'int16', 'uint16', 'int32', 'uint32', 'int64', and 'uint64'.

So this suggests me that it is not supported directly by the existing functions.

**So my attempt to make the this logical random number generator and applying the function through a mask**

```
clear;
close all;
image = imread('contour.png');
load('mask_1.mat');
areaLazyRemoval = BW;
image = image(:,:,1);
image  = conditional_removal(image, areaLazyRemoval);
image = double(image);
contour(image);
colorbar;
caxis([-2,1.5].*10^7);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function matrix = make_random_logical_matrix(matrix)

[row_max,column_max] = size(matrix);
matrix = randn(row_max,column_max);
for row = 1:row_max
    for column = 1:column_max
        t = randn;
        if t >= 0
            matrix(row,column) = 0;
        end
        if t < 0
            matrix(row,column) = 1;
        end
    end
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function [ image ] = conditional_removal( image, areaLazyRemoval )
    random_logical_matrix = make_random_logical_matrix(areaLazyRemoval);
    areaLazyRemoval = areaLazyRemoval .* random_logical_matrix;
    areaLazyRemoval = uint8(areaLazyRemoval);
    image = image(:,:,1) .* areaLazyRemoval;
end
```

and the contour

[image]

and the mesh

[image]

which seems to be ok solution.
To improve, I think the norm of the situation should be calculated and then the **conditional_removal** algorithm improved accordingly.